# Problem to iterate through a nested JSON API with NEXTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, next.js

I struggle to consume nested json API into with NEXTJS
Precisely, I fail to extract a nested dictionary from the API file, i.e. a dictionary in a dictionary.

In the example below I manage to consume only the first-level entries.
Ex: component name renders CardsPage
It doesn't work though for nested files. Ex  the "cards" entries

Since the cards is an array, I iterated through it with cards.map.
This allowed me to consume the first level map item (here: type), while all other fields remain blank, i.e I don't call them correctly.

Any tip, advice on how to make it work, would be highly appreciated.

The API entries in my JSON are:
Some entries were omitted for the sake of brevity:CardsPage.js

CardsPage.js

```js
...imports...

const CardsPage = ({ title, comments, cards }) => {
    return (
        <div className={s['CardsPage']}>
            <p> title:{title} </p>
            <RawHtml html={comments} />

        <div>
        {cards.map((card, key) => (
        <div>
            <p>{card.type}</p>
            <p>{card.value.title}</p>
            <img src={card.value.image.src} alt="BigCo Inc. logo"/>
       </div>
   ))}
   </div>

   </div>
   );
};

CardsPage.defaultProps = {
    title: '',
    cards: '',
    image: '',
};

CardsPage.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    image: PropTypes.string.isrequired,
    ...
};

export default basePageWrap(CardsPage);
```

JSON API

```js
{
    "component_name": "CardsPage",
    "component_props": {
        "title": "Sea creatures",
         ...
  
        "cards": [
            {
                "type": "card",
                "value": {
                    "image": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "whale",
                        "original": {
                            "src": "/wt/media/images/whale.original.jpg",
                            "width": 512,
                            "height": 512,
                            "alt": "whale"
                        },
                    },
                    "card_title": "Whale",
                    "card_hint": "biggest"
                },
                "id": "c83003cf-4ee6-473f-a6b5-5a021bfc2fbd"
            },
           ...
        ],

    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `value.title` in your card but `value.image.title` or `value.card_title`

Comment: Thanks. You were right. that was missing. I amended it, in my answer. NB - as you didn't mention the 'original' I answered the question to provide a more detail solution. If you find that your should get he credit for the answer, kindly advise, I'll amend the necessary and give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the lack of 'original' container in the CardsPage.js before the image's props.

The code specifies:

```html
{cards.map((card, key) => (
        <div>
            <p>{card.type}</p>
            <p>{card.value.title}</p>
            <img src={card.value.image.src} alt="BigCo Inc. logo"/>
       </div>
```

Yet, as the API file shows there is 'orginal' container before the image props, so it should be:

```html
{cards.map((card, key) => (
        <div>
            <p>{card.type}</p>
            <p>{card.value.image.title}</p>
            <img src={card.value.image.original.src} alt="BigCo Inc. logo"/>
       </div>
```

NB - I also amended the value.image.title